# Failed to sign apk - unrecognized algorithm name

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

**Describe the bug**
- I tried to package my mobile app for the Android Play Store and used a previous keystore. This keystore has a "Keystore Password" that is 7 characters long and a "Key Alias" that is 5 characters long. The publishing gets to the end but then errors.

**To Reproduce**

1. Publish - Distribute - Android Play Store
2. Signing errors with the following:

```
[INFO] :   Writing unsigned apk: **omitted**
[INFO] :   Using MD5withRSA (weak) signature algorithm
[INFO] :   Signing apk: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner "-sigalg" "MD5withRSA (weak)" "-digestalg" "SHA1" "-keystore" "/dev_keystore" "-storepass" "*******" "-signedjar" "Name.apk" "../app-unsigned.apk" "tidev"
[ERROR] :  Failed to sign apk:
[ERROR] :  jarsigner error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: MD5withRSA (weak)
```

**Expected behavior**
Expected the app to be signed. I haven't had issues in the past.

**Environment**

- Titanium SDK version: 7.5.1 GA
- CLI version: 5.1.1

**Logs**:

```
[INFO] :   Writing unsigned apk: **omitted**
[INFO] :   Using MD5withRSA (weak) signature algorithm
[INFO] :   Signing apk: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner "-sigalg" "MD5withRSA (weak)" "-digestalg" "SHA1" "-keystore" "/dev_keystore" "-storepass" "*******" "-signedjar" "Name.apk" "../app-unsigned.apk" "tidev"
[ERROR] :  Failed to sign apk:
[ERROR] :  jarsigner error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: MD5withRSA (weak)
```

Comment: it seems you need to improve the algo

Comment: @RenePot - I have Android apps published on the Play store that already use this keystore. If I can't use this keystore anymore I won't be able to update apps already using this keystore correct?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed that it should be a JAVA problem. Have a look at:
https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/kb/java-update-compatability-md5.html

and try to change/add `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024` in this file: `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\java.security`

For new apps I would recommend creating a new signing key